# How can I set the ls program dired uses only for local directories

Tags: dired, tramp, remote

I have set the ls program dired uses via

```
(setq insert-directory-program "gls"))
```

(so that I can specify `--group-directories-first` in `dired-listing-switches`).

Trouble is when I browse a remote directory, TRAMP seems to use the same variable `insert-directory-program`, but on arbitrary remote machines the `gls` command might not be available.

How can I set the `ls` program dired uses to `gls` only for local directories?

Comment: What (local) system are you running on? Have you built `gls` in e.g. `/usr/local/bin` with the system `ls` in `/usr/bin`?

Comment: @NickD Thanks for chiming in! I am on macOS Mojave (Intel) and installed GNU coreutils via Homebrew. So, yes, `gls` is in `/usr/local/bin` and the standard `ls` is in `/bin`.

Comment: So you could set your PATH (and emacs's `exec-path`) to have `/usr/local/bin` first and rename `gls` to `ls`. Then restore the default for `insert-directory-program`: that way, you (and emacs) would get the `ls` that knows about `--group-directories-first` and you'd be happy and since you don't change the default, `tramp` would use that and everybody else would be happy too. People on your machine who have not set their PATH that way (either not including it at all or including it *after* `/bin`) would get the system `ls` and presumably they would be happy too. Any reason this wouldn't work?

Comment: @NickD That's probably the way to go. I just had hoped that there were separate variables for local and remote dired...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Elaborating on the comments form @NickD there seems to be no separate way to configure the used `ls` command used used for TRAMP directories vs local directories.

So the remaining option is to symlink the local `gls` (at least for Emacs) to `ls` and keep Emacs' default of `insert-directory-program` as  `"ls"`.

#### Update 28 Sep 2021:

Also, it is important to use no non-standard switches in `dired-listing-switches`, because they are used for the remote dired buffers as well! So stick with something like `"-alhF"` and don't use GNU's `--group-directories-first`, beacuse your TRAMP dired buffere will be empty when the remote system for example plain BSD.

Comment: Another option _might_ be to use `ls-lisp` instead of a OS-level `ls`, but I don't know what `ls-lisp` does for remote directories. - Will test it!